# consume external api from apache camel XML

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have a service with apache camel that must verify an email and it is this:

```
http://localhost:8017/camel/v1/common-validations/email/mymail@gmail.com
```

This service calls an api that is on another server and the url is this:

```
http://services/api/Validations/ValidarMail
```

When I consume this api, it returns the following error:

```
[Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid uri: /camel/v1/common-
validations/email/mymail@gmail.com/v1/common-validations/email/mymail@gmail.com.If you are
forwarding/bridging http endpoints, then enable the bridgeEndpoint option on the endpoint:
http://services/api/Validations/ValidarMail]
```

It's like repeating part of the route:

```
Invalid uri: /camel/v1/common-validations/email/mymail@gmail.com/v1/common-validations/email/mymail@gmail.com
```

bridgeEndpoint must be false because otherwise it adds /camel/v1/common-validations/email/mymail@gmail.com to http://services/api/Validations/ValidarMail and it would look like this
http://servicios/api/Validaciones/ValidarCorreo/camel/v1/validaciones-comunes/email/micoreo@gmail.com

Part of the code I use is the following:

```
       <rest path="/v1/validaciones-comunes/email">
        <get uri="/{correo}" produces="application/json"  outType="Boolean">
            <to uri="direct:validaEmail" />
        </get>
    </rest>
    <route id="validaEmail" streamCache="true" >
        <from uri="direct:validaEmail"/>
        
         <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="|*****===>ResponseBody: ${body}"/>
            <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="|*****===>ResponseHeaders.email: ${in.headers.correo}"/>
        <doTry>               
            <setHeader name="Content-Type"><constant>application/json</constant></setHeader>
            <setHeader name="CamelHttpMethod"><constant>POST</constant></setHeader>
            <setBody><simple>${in.headers.correo}</simple></setBody>
            <toD uri="http://servicios/api/Validaciones/ValidarCorreo/" />
             <setBody><simple>${body}</simple></setBody>
            <doCatch>
                <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                <log logName="cl.backend" loggingLevel="ERROR" message="Excepcion: ${exception}" />
                 <setBody><simple>${exception}</simple></setBody>
            </doCatch>

        </doTry>
    </route>
```

If you could help me identify the problem I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to remove the headers except the ones you need.

```
<removeHeaders pattern="*" excludePattern="mail" />
```

before

```
<setHeader name="Content-Type"><constant>application/json</constant></setHeader>
```